# "Backup Operators" Not Working [cobian]

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I'm trying to run Cobian Backup on our file server under it's own user (instead of `Administrator`).

It is unable to backup our user homes/profiles since making the change.

The dedicated user `cobianbup` is a member of the domain group `Backup Operators`

I've tried adding the domain `Backup Operators` to the following User Rights Assignments with no luck:

```
Act as part of the operating system
Back up files and directories
Create a token object
Log on a a batch job
Log on a a service
Restore files and directories
Take ownership of files or other objects
```

I even added the `cobianbup` user explicitly to the local `Backup Operators` group and it still won't work.

I've had to add `cobianbup` to the local `Administrators` group to get it working. I restarted the service after each change to make sure and changes were picked up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The domain group Backup Operators is in the Builtin container.
The Builtin container is like the standard Local groups you would find on a standalone PC or server (non DC), however it is shared across all domain controllers. Domain Controllers don't have "local" users or groups (try finding it in computer management - it's not there).

I'm assuming your files are not stored on a Domain Controller, so what you'll need to do is add your cobianbup user to the local Backup Operators group on the file server. You can create a GPO that can do this for all servers that are needed.

Comment: "I even added the "cobianbup" user explicitly to the local "Backup Operators" group and it still won't work." You are correct that the file server is not a DC.